# Build library with ressources

Tags: c#, dll, build, embedded-resource

I made a library which uses .xml files for configuration. But in the core project, which use this library, ressources are not copied. I added a reference to my library.dll but of course there is nothing that says i need to include /configuration folder of the lib project.

How can i achieve that ? (manual copy is excluded)

ps: im working in c# with visual studio 2012 ultimate. both project are c#. One generate a library (dll etc..), other is executable project.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

Right click and select Add > Existing item to include the resources into your project.

After including them, select them under the Solution Explorer, right click and select properties. Look for `Copy to Output Directory`, and set it to `Always`. That should copy the files along with your project.

Another option if needed, may be to set `Build Action` to `Embedded Resource`, but that might make it a little more complicated (but not impossible) to access the files from your application.

Update: Accessing a file that is embedded is a little more messy, but this [other SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3314140/how-to-read-embedded-resource-text-file) might help you out.

Comment: My ressource are correctly copied in the /release or /debug folder, it's working as expected for the lib project. The issue is : When i include this library into an another project, it didn't copy .xml files. So in the another project i have a IOexception because there is not file anymore :s

Comment: Im pretty sure if i copy, by hands, the /configuration folder of my lib projecto into the /release folder of the core project, it would work. But i don't want to do this, by hands:s

Comment: Ok.. Then I suspect you might need to use my second option: If you include the files as embedded resources, they should be included _in_ the `.dll`, and so you should be able to access them from the second project too.

Comment: This way, i lost all the benefit of having a configuration file in xml which i can modify without having to rebuild whole project:s
edit : plus i use this .xml files for configuration which i can modify from code or by hand , depend on situation. If it's embbeded in the .dll, i could serialize again those file ( well i think). Am i correct ?